# Bootstrap Baguette box works on desktop PC but does not work on a Mobile phone

Tags: mobile, bootstrap-4, gallery, responsive

I have a bootstrap gallery on my website. when i click an image, the image enlarges and i can select a left or right arrow on either side of the image to go to the next or previous image. this works on a computer, however it does not work on a mobile. I am using Bootstrap baguette box for this. below is the code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"/> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.8.1/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.8.1/baguetteBox.min.css">

    <!-- compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">    
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
<!-- The above links connect javascript, bootstrap and the CSS stylesheet to the web page.  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- The above links connect a stylesheet and jquery scripts to the web page.  -->
</head>
<div class="bg">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1>Sports Line</h1>
    </div>   

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light justify-content-between">

 <div class="btn-toolbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav inline-navbar">
  <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Home</a>
<br>
  <a href="teams.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Teams</a>
<br>
  <a href="gallery.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Gallery</a>        <!-- This code is for the navigation bar on the webpages.  -->
<br>
  <a href="stats.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Stats</a>
<br>
  <a href="stadiums.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Stadiums</a>
<br>
  <a href="info.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Info</a>
</ul>
</div>

</nav> 

    <div class="galleryheading">
      <h2>Gallery</h2>
    </div>  
     </div> 
    <body>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>

<div class="container gallery-container">

    <div class="tz-gallery">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="lightbox" href="photos/galleryimage.jpg">
                        <img src="photos/galleryimage.jpg" alt="Chelsea v liecester">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Chelsea V Liecester</h3>
                        <p>Alvaro Morata working his way through the Leicester defence</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="lightbox" href="photos/galleryimage1.jpg">
                        <img src="photos/galleryimage1.jpg" alt="Manchester United">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Manchester United victory</h3>
                        <p>Manchester United celebrating after winning the FA cup <br><br></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="lightbox" href="photos/galleryimage2.jpg">
                        <img src="photos/galleryimage2.jpg" alt="Premier league">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Premier League Players</h3>
                        <p>Players from Manchester United, Manchster City, Tottenham, Liverpool, Chelsea and Arsenal</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="lightbox" href="photos/galleryimage3.jpg">
                        <img src="photos/galleryimage3.jpg" alt="Chelsea celebrating">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Chelsea celebrating after winning the premier league in 2017</h3>
                        <p>Chelsea finished at the top of the premier league table in 2017.</p>      <!-- This code displays images as well as captions as a gallery.  -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="lightbox" href="photos/galleryimage4.jpg">
                        <img src="photos/galleryimage4.jpg" alt="Stadium">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Old Trafford Stadium</h3>
                        <p>Manchester United's home football ground, known as Old Trafford. <br><br></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="lightbox" href="photos/galleryimage5.jpg">
                        <img src="photos/galleryimage5.jpg" alt="logos">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Team logos</h3>
                        <p>The most popular football team logos. <br><br><br></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<script>
    baguetteBox.run('.tz-gallery');    <!-- This is for the gallery. it is there to allow the user to click the next or previous arrow when images are enlarged -->
</script>

</html>
      <div id="dialog-2" title="Dialog Title goes here...">If you have any queries or would like to request further information on your favourite football team, please do not hesitate to contact us. We will be more than happy to help.<br><br>Tel:01484213476<br><br>Email:u1555602@unimail.hud.ac.uk<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;saleemm070@gmail.com<br><br>Address: 12 Queen Street<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Huddersfield<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;HD3&nbsp;4GL</div> 
</body>
    </div>
```

My css code is:

```
/* Variables used for font and h1 color */
.gallery-container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-family: Serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8c8c8c; }

/* Variable used for gallery color */
.gallery-container p.page-description {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #8c8c8c; }

.tz-gallery {
  padding: 40px; }

.tz-gallery .thumbnail {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06); }

.tz-gallery .thumbnail:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px) scale(1.02); }

.tz-gallery .lightbox img {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; }

.tz-gallery .caption {
  padding: 26px 30px;
  text-align: center; }

.tz-gallery .caption h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 0; }

.tz-gallery .caption p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #2F4F4F;
  margin: 0; }

.baguetteBox-button {
  background-color: transparent !important; }
```

Comment: Can you show your css code?

Comment: @JordanMiguel sorry for the late reply. i have added the css code to the question

Comment: Have you had a look at this? - https://github.com/feimosi/baguetteBox.js#responsive-images